# How to separate tags from formatted-text with XSLT-1?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need to split a mixed "tags and text" XML, into two "pure" parts: one part with only data-tags (any tag that is not a `<b>`, `<i>` or `<sup>` format-tags); o other part with "only text" (`//text()` and format-tags).

*Input example:*

```
  <root>
    Nonono <i>nonon</i> <data1/> <b>nono</b> 
    <data2>nononono <i>no</i>nononon</data2>.
    <data3>blablabla<data4/></data3>
  </root>
```

*Output example:*

```
  <root>
    <myTags>
       <data1/>
       <data2>nononono <i>no</i>nononon</data2>
       <data3>blablabla<data4/></data3>  
    </myTags>

    <myText>
      Nonono <i>nonon</i> <b>nono</b> 
      nononono <i>no</i>nononon . blablabla
    </myText>
  </root>
```

---

*Edited* with one input that is more realistic,

```
    Nonono <i>nonon</i> <data1/> <b>nono <data66/> </b>
```

must outputs

```
       <data1/><data66/>
```

this case express a problem a little bit more complex. It can be occurs into any level.

---

Below the `xsl:transform` core of my XSLT (that NOT WORKS!),

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
    <myTags><xsl:call-template name="copyOnlyTags"/></myTags>
    <myText><xsl:call-template name="copyOnlyTextAndFormat"/></myText>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<!-- LIB -->

<xsl:template name="copyOnlyTags">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="node()[not(self::text())]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="count(*)=0">    <!-- terminal -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>        <!-- recurrence -->
            <xsl:call-template name="copyOnlyTags"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="copyOnlyTextAndFormat">
        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="name()='i' or name()='sup' or name()='sub' or name()='b'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/><!-- suppose only text into -->
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>        <!-- recurrence -->
            <xsl:call-template name="copyOnlyTextAndFormat"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is not about telling the processor what you want it to do, it is about stating what result you want to have.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <myTags>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="data" />
      </myTags>
      <myText>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="format" />
      </myText>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- unless stated otherwise, we want no output -->
  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="data" />
  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="format" />

  <!-- DATA MODE: data elements should be copied -->
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'data')]" mode="data">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- DATA MODE: format elements should be passed silently -->
  <xsl:template match="*[not(starts-with(name(), 'data'))]" mode="data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="data" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- FORMAT MODE: format elements and text nodes should be copied -->
  <xsl:template match="text() | *[not(starts-with(name(), 'data'))]" mode="format">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="format" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- FORMAT MODE: data elements should be passed silently -->
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'data')]" mode="format">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="format" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

For

```
<root>
    Nonono <i>nonon</i> <data1/> <b>nono</b> 
    <data2>nononono <i>no</i>nononon</data2>.
    <data3>blablabla<data4/></data3>
</root>
```

The output is

```
<root>
  <myTags>
    <data1/>
    <data2>nononono <i>no</i>nononon</data2>
    <data3>blablabla<data4/></data3>
  </myTags>
  <myText>
    Nonono <i>nonon</i>  <b>nono</b> 
    nononono <i>no</i>nononon.
    blablabla
  </myText>
</root>
```

for

```
<root>
    Nonono <i>nonon</i> <data1/> <b>nono <data66/> </b> 
</root>
```

it produces

```
<root>
  <myTags>
    <data1/>
    <data66/>
  </myTags>
  <myText>
    Nonono <i>nonon</i>  <b>nono  </b> 
  </myText>
</root>
```

Comment: Hum, I haved problems with `copy-of` because destroys order (I need to preserve sequence); and I need the identity-transform because data1, data2, is only examples, can be "any other thing" (data4, data5, x, y, ... any other tag that is not a formating one).

Comment: *"any other thing"* could be `*` or `node()` or `*[not(self:i or self::b)]`, depending on how the rest of your transformation is set up.

Comment: Yes, `*[not(self:i or self::b)]` is the "rest"... Ops, check my edited output for `myText`, is not the same as yours.

Comment: Check my second stylesheet which deals with "data" elements nested in "format" elements. Its output is exactly as your sample indicates. Add `<xsl:output format="yes" />` if you fancy that.

Comment: I have a problem with my XSLT-1-processor, *LibXML2* (embeded into PHP): `*[not(self:i or self::b)]` cause an error, I must to use `*[name()!='i' and name()!='b']`; with this changes, ok, your `mode="format"` is working (50% of the problem solved!). About your `mode="data"`, check my "real problem", now illustred by `data66` in the question text (edited)... I need to "clean data-tags from external texts", and use data that is into a formater-tag.

Comment: Also note that `<xsl:copy-of select="//text()[parent::root | parent::*[starts-with(name(), 'data')]] | //i | //b" />` would produce the right output in the first stylesheet.

Comment: Try again with `*[not(self::i or self::b)]`, there was a colon missing (you could have spotted that...)

Comment: Writing solutions here is a time-consuming activity, please do not also make it a frustrating one by posting bogus problems and then coming about with the "real problem" after somebody already invested time in an answer. :-(

Comment: Sorry... Thank for all clues and solutions (!). Yes, I voted to your answer because is a solution. I not declared the "real problem" because is very complex, and with `xsl:copy-of` I can work: now I running a second XSLT with only a `<xsl:template match="tag1/text()|tag2/text()|tag2/tag4/text()|..."/>` that cleans all residual texts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39758/discussion-between-peter-krauss-and-tomalak)